# python, how to detect attributes or functions that defined in class but never called by the instance of class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As you know, when the project's code is very large and there are so many attributes and functions defined in a Class, but some of them never be called by the instance of the Class, and maybe some of them has been discarded. Here is a example:

```
class Foo(object):
    """"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
        ...
        self.y = 25
        self.z = 26

    def func1(self):
        pass

    def func2(self):
        pass

    def func3(self):
        pass
    ...
    ...
    def func100(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo()
    f.func1()
    f.func2()
    print f.a, f.b, f.z
```

In the above code, the instance *f* of class *Foo* just called *func1()* and *func2()*. And how to find all the attributes and functions of class that never called by the instance of class.

I have tried `compiler` module but that could not solve my question. And `dir(my_instance)` is just print all the functions and attributes defined the the class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to find a code analysis tool, something like: [vulture](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vulture) or [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) but these tools all come with a lot of caveats given Python's dynamic nature.

Comment: Interesting question, if you ignore the context. Generally speaking, I don't how it can be possible. You get attributes of a class dynamically, says, based on user input. Anyway, usually you should have unit/integration tests to check your code after refactoring. To check for direct usage, you can use an IDE (I'm not a big fun of them so cannot recommend one).

Comment: ＠khachik, though python is a dynamic language, I use `__slot__` to restrict dynamic binding,  that is the user can not bind a attribute if it is not in slots.

Comment: "when the project's code is very large and there are so many attributes and functions defined in a Class" This is a problem. A class should not grow indefinitely. If I saw a class with 100 functions, I would look at breaking it up *immediately*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard to prove something is or is not used in the general case. Python is a dynamic language; if even one bit of code calls into code the static analyzer doesn't fully analyze, it could be accessing the variables mentioned.

The `pylint` and `flake8` tools will tell you about local and global names that aren't defined prior to use (unless you break them by using `from x import *` style imports), and about imports that are never used (an import that is never used is usually wrong, but even then, it could be an intentional part of the interface, where linters would have to be silenced), but I don't believe they can tell you that a given attribute is never accessed; after all, someone else could import your module and access said attributes.

Comment: Another example would be if someone imports your code into the REPL for direct use instead of scripting. There would never be a way to detect that since it would only exist at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`coverage.py`](https://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/coverage-4.0.3/). It's not static analysis, but actually runs your code and records which statements are executed, outputting annotated html or txt as you wish (quite nicely formatted as well). You can then look for functions and methods whose bodies are not executed at all.

This still doesn't take care of unused *attributes*. And I don't know the answer to that. Maybe comment them out one at a time and see if tests still pass...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [profile](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/profile.html) module in the standard library.

```
python -m cProfile -o output_file myscript.py
```

Then load the stats file and use `print_callees()` to get all the functions that were called--during that run of the program.

I don't know of any easy way to find out which attributes are used.